# Is there a mistake in the expression for clean behavior in Pnueli's article from 81'?

Tags: concurrency, linear-temporal-logic

I am reading an article called [The temporal semantics of concurrent programs](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science?_ob=MiamiImageURL&_cid=271538&_user=32321&_pii=0304397581901109&_check=y&_origin=article&_zone=toolbar&_coverDate=31-Dec-1981&view=c&originContentFamily=serial&wchp=dGLzVlV-zSkWb&md5=2073f527aa2be434886953d7aaa0f7d3&pid=1-s2.0-0304397581901109-main.pdf)
.

On page $9$, there is a small section (numbered as $2$) called "clean behavior".

I think that there is a problem with this part, what does Pnueli meant by "Let $\lambda_i$ be the leagality condition for **the** statement departing from $m^i$" ?

I have marked the word "the" in bold since, as I see it, there can be more than one edge departing from $m^i$, an example can be seen on page $11$, at the beginning of part $5$.

Did I missunderstood something , or is there actually a mistake in the article by not addressing the fact that there can be more than one statement that can be exectuded after $m^i$, and that this expression for clean behavior need to be corrected accordingly ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would seem that in (1) (still page 9) he refers to a sequential program, so there is no concurrency. I think this assumption holds for the rest of the articles. So the "the" is ok there.